# Issue making bootstrap responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a single page of my website which I'm struggling to make responsive. It looks fine on normal screens but is very small and doesn't fill the whole screen on an iPhone. I've narrowed the issue down to this block of code:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="post-preview">
          <h2 class="post-title">Blah</h2>
          <p>Blah</p>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="post-preview">
          <h2 class="post-title">Blah</h2>
          <p>Blah</p>

          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="post-preview">
          <h2>Blah</h2>
          <p class="post-title">Blog Post</p>
          <p class="post-title">Blog Post</p>
          <p class="post-title">Blog Post</p>

          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I think I'm not using the grid system properly but would welcome any input!

My source is here: http://pastebin.com/JC6XzTMT and I'm using this as a base: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-clean-blog/
Thanks

Comment: Please post a complete, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet. You haven't provided nearly enough information. [mcve]

Comment: reproduce the issue in fiddle

Comment: Here you go! http://pastebin.com/JC6XzTMT I'm using this template as a base if that helps: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-clean-blog/

Comment: If you want it to fill the whole screen, you need to use 'container-fluid' instead of 'container'. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Comment: Aha! That helped, it works :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following meta tag is the `head` of your page:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Hi there - I have already added this though thanks for the tip :)